# Remapping keys on keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I just bought a new 61-key keyboard from [here](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/mechanical-keyboard/wasd-vp3-61-key-custom-mechanical-keyboard.html). Since the arrow-keys are absent from this keyboard, I am wondering if I can remap for instance CAPS+WASD to act as arrow keys. The software I find online can only handle singe key remapping, not combinations of keys.

Comment: What apps have your tried so far? Are you seeking a software recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a [manual](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/media/vp3-user-guide.pdf) for my keyboard. Information on mapping is all in there. Interesting, did not know this stuff actually sat in the actual keyboard, thought it was a OS/software thing.